# VSTS/TFS extension reinstall after remove, The extension already exists

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

*VSTS/TFS(2017) version id: 15.117.26714.0*

I has uninstalled my custom extension, and it was removed this extensions list.Then I reinstalled itsef, alert 'The extension already exists'.Amazing, query the url `http://{domain}/tfs/_apis/gallery/publishers/{publishers}/extensions/{extensionId}`, I can get uninstall extension info.

I found two way to resolve it, but they don't work well.Way as below.

- clean the client caches :

  1. TFS:  C:\Users{your account}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TeamFoundation{version}\Cache
  2. Browser, IE for example (based on your settings) : C:\Users{your account}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
     Emmmm, there is no INetCache dir.I skip it.
- query the TFS REST API

  `﻿curl "http://{domain}/tfs/_apis/gallery/publishers/{publisher}/extensions/{extensionId}" -X DELETE -H "Pragma: no-cache" -H ......`
  However,it throw some error:

  { 
  "message":"TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access.Client authentication required.",
  "type":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.UnauthorizedRequestException",
  "isRemoteException":false,
  "errorCode":0,
  "eventId":3000
  } 
  While I change other extension publisher and extensionId , it success.

Comment: Try to use `tfx build tasks delete --task-id xxxxxx` to [delete the task](https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli/blob/master/docs/buildtasks.md). And check the ID of your extension in vss-extension.json file, and change the ID to have another try.

Comment: I had resolved it. Using `curl`  to get code in postman,and run it in chrome's  console.To my surprise, I get this response that its code is 404.Even if this request may be some question, I get nothing my extension info when I query the api again.I can't change task id or extension id, then I will lose my important history data.

Comment: You mentioned "I had resolved it", do you mean you can re-install the extension now?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and I can solved it with REST API

```
DELETE https://{domain}/tfs/_apis/gallery/publishers/{publisher}/extensions/{extension-name}?api-version=3.2-preview.2
```

Change is not use extensionsID but I use extension name as resource identification

I execute request via Fiddler with basic auth and using PAT instead of username/password